# Why is the result of -128 & 0xf0 different than what I get with bit-shifting operations?

Tags: java, bit, operation

Recently working on Bluetooth related products, I need to send byte instructions and java bit arithmetic.

```
byte byt = -128;
System.out.println(byt);
String s2 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(byt & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s2);

String s3 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((byt >> 4) & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s3);

String s4 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((byt & 0xf0) & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s4);

String s5 = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((byt & 0xf0)>>4 & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
System.out.println(s5);
```

Here is the output print:

```
System.out: -128
System.out: 10000000
System.out: 11111000
System.out: 10000000
System.out: 00001000
```

I know -128 is a critical value, but why the result of "& 0xf0" and ">> 4" is different from the direct ">> 4" result?

Comment: Does the title accurately reflect the question? (I edited to make it more specific because that makes it easier for other people to know whether the question is relevant to them or not).

Comment: Interesting question BTW, +1 from me. I'd actually like to see the answer to this too.

Comment: Because `& 0xf0` leaves the result in the upper 4 bits, and the shift leaves it in the lower 4. The operations aren't equivalent.

Comment: Thank you all, I think I know the answer, because -128 becomes +128 after &0xf0

Comment: No it isn't, and no it doesn't. It is because `>>` shifts the bits and `&` doesn't. Your question never made sense.

Comment: You're right, I don't quite understand why -128 becomes 128 after &0xf0?

Comment: It doesn't. Read what I wrote.